# Rails 3.2 - Why am I getting mass-assign protection error despite using .save(validate: false)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, mass-assignment

I have a `Timesheet` model without many of its attributes added to `attr_accessible`. Trying to create seed data in `seeds.rb` but am getting a mass-assign protection error both when running `rake db:seed` as well as when trying the code in the console despite using `.save(validate: false)`.

Error ouput from `rake db:seed`:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: spent, worked_time, driving_time
```

console:

```
pry(main)> ts = Timesheet.new(spent: 0, review: "none", driving_time: 0, worked_time: 3600).save(validate: false)
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: spent, driving_time, worked_time
from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activemodel-3.2.18/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this:

```
ts = Timesheet.new({spent: 0, review: "none", driving_time: 0, worked_time: 3600}, 
without_protection: true).save(validate: false)
```

more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/security.html#mass-assignment)

The best practices says that you must white list the fields you want the user update at the model with `attr_accessible :spent, :driving_time, :worked_time` if you expect your user send this data with the update or create form.

The option `validate: false` prevents the validation before save, but not the mass assignment control.

Answer (score 2):

You need to skip mass-assignment, `.save(validate: false)` only skips validations.

Try passing option:

```
:without_protection => true
```

what you need to do is:

```
ts = Timesheet.new(spent: 0, review: "none", driving_time: 0, worked_time: 3600, :without_protection => true).save(validate: false)
```